# Visualization of an array in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, visualization

I am trying to visualize a random array with the square shape of (10, 10) in Python using matplotlib (3.5 version). I am also including the xaxis and yaxis ticks, but the ticks for 10 show empty data. Does anyone know how to sort it out?

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pylab as pylab
params = {'legend.fontsize': 'medium',
          'figure.figsize': (15, 5),
         'axes.labelsize': 'x-large',
         'axes.titlesize':'x-large',
         'xtick.labelsize':'x-large',
         'ytick.labelsize':'x-large'}
pylab.rcParams.update(params)

arr = np.random.rand(10, 10)
plt.imshow(arr)
plt.ylim(0, 10)
plt.xlim(0, 10)

plt.xticks(np.arange(0.0, 11.0, 1.0))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0.0, 11.0, 1.0))

plt.show()
```

This is the produced image:

[image]

Comment: Because arrays are zero indexed in python, and you are asking for an array of size 10, so 0-9?

Comment: The pyhton arrays starts it's indexin in 0. So you will have values between 0-9 in both axis, note that also every tick points to the center of "pixel". You could modify your lims `plt.xlim((-0.5,9.5))` and `plt.ylim((-0.5,9.5))`. Last if you really need the numbers to be between 1 and 10 you could use xticks and yticks: `plt.xticks(np.arange(10), np.arange(1,11)) ` and `plt.yticks(np.arange(10), np.arange(1,11)) ` 

Note that if you want the tick to start at left-down corner of pixel you can play with the first arange in ticks (i think it must be `np.arange(-0.5,9.5,1)` but im not sure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other users pointed, Python arrays start indexing in '0'. You could trick the ticks to show the values you want:

1. create data to plot

   ```
   import numpy as np

   from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
   import matplotlib.pylab as pylab
   params = {'legend.fontsize': 'medium',
             'figure.figsize': (15, 5),
            'axes.labelsize': 'x-large',
            'axes.titlesize':'x-large',
            'xtick.labelsize':'x-large',
            'ytick.labelsize':'x-large'}
   pylab.rcParams.update(params)

   arr = np.random.rand(10, 10)
   ```
2. Then you can use `plt.xticks(tickPosition,tickValues)` and same with yticks. Note that every number point to the center of every value in your image so also you have to change your lim positions:

```
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(arr)
    plt.ylim(-0.5, 9.5) #to show no blank spaces
    plt.xlim(-0.5, 9.5) #to show no blank spaces
    
    plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 10),np.arange(1, 11)) #trick the ticks
    plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 10),np.arange(1, 11))
```

This will give you the next figure

[image: Tricked points]

3. Also you can set values at start (left-down corner) just tricking a little more:

```
    plt.xticks(np.arange(-0.5, 9.5),np.arange(1, 11))
    plt.yticks(np.arange(-0.5, 9.5),np.arange(1, 11))
```

this will give you this result:

[image: with ticks at "start" of pixel]